# Register/login user with Wordpress JSON API

Tags: json, wordpress

I want to create mobile app for one wordpress website. I have integrated  the [wordpress json plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/).
I'm not sure where I can find service for user registration and login.
Please advice.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/mattberg/wp-json-api-auth. It will handle user login, but not registration. It's been working well for me in a native app I'm building.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To register a user [this](http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-remotely-create-a-user-on-your-wordpress-website-using-json-api-request/) will show you exactly how to register one on the database by simply calling a url and adding data to it using [GET Method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).
Now to do so from a mobile app you just have to make an http request to a url containing all the data required for the user. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android) will show you how to make a request from Android.

This is just for registering users there will be another plugin [JSON APi Auth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-auth/) used in order to login a user.

These are the basics since I don't have much time now, when I do, I will provide full details and example. But for now this shall do it

Answer (score 34):

1.Paste Following code in your themes `function.php` file.

2.Make sure that `WP-REST-API` plugin Should be installed on wordpress site

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );

function register_api_hooks() {
  register_rest_route(
    'custom-plugin', '/login/',
    array(
      'methods'  => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'login',
    )
  );
}

function login($request){
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $request["username"];
    $creds['user_password'] =  $request["password"];
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
      echo $user->get_error_message();

    return $user;
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

Then your API will be created as

```
http://www.url.com/wp-json/custom-plugin/login
```

Try it with Postman You will get `200` as a response and `user info`

Comment: This is the easiest way i saw over all answers i found.. thanks man.

Comment: though it give me response in browser but where ever i make an http request from android, or even php, script doesn't see any data, android says: FileNotFoundExeption

Comment: I'm not sure that the last add_action is necessary.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error with status code 404 - rest_no_route. Please help me

Comment: This is spectacular, thank you! Can you also login users with their email?

Comment: @Ganesh Hargude: Can you please help me with how to create WooCommerce Forgot Password API? By using your above example I have created Login API and that working well.

Comment: I would like to point out that wp_sigon() function will auto select to use secure cookie or not, I would suggest to set the $user variable as such
$user = wp_signon($creds);

Comment: For login information with passwords you want to use POST not GET

Comment: Thank you so much for this! How do I make a call to this, is it secure to just send the password in an AJAX call from a remote server?

Answer (score 12):

I was able to figure out both **login and signup** using **@Salam El-Bannas' [link](http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-remotely-create-a-user-on-your-wordpress-website-using-json-api-request/)**, in case any one still needs this here you go:

All through you need two plugins to get the job done:

[WordPress JSON API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

and

[JSON API User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/)

1. **For registration of users:** You need **nonce ID** which will be a part of the registration params in the GET url process (this is provided by the plugins). Read @Salam El-Bannas' [link](http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-remotely-create-a-user-on-your-wordpress-website-using-json-api-request/) for more understanding. The methodology i used in android was that immediately the page loads I block the UI with "Connecting..." message while in the background am getting the nonce ID once its done the UI Blocking disappears and the nonce ID is added to a special non-editable EditText field created for the nonce ID, the user then enters his/her required credentials and I authenticate that its valid before connecting to the server using the nonce ID i got. the result from the server is JSON so i can handle the rest in android code using volley and GSON.
2. For Login of users: You only need cookies ID generated by the plugin eg in my case `http://localhost/mylocalhost/my_api_base/user/generate_auth_cookie/?insecure=cool&email=xxx@xdfer.org&password=xxxv678`

and the result was this json;

`{"status":"ok","cookie":"xxxx|1486130938|Ot6yAX7iU773JnQ2zfE8sdmjt09LhHqDKSYBqtekuha|7fe58a35ab9f260c9bced9148f5cf9ae3ab56c16d7d9ce3b2db7da651d4d937d","cookie_name":"wordpress_logged_in_4132d8131ebbc6760d21627637bd4b20","user":{"id":1,"username":"administrator","nicename":"administrator","email":"xxx@xdfer.org","url":"","registered":"2016-11-02 17:46:19","displayname":"xxxx","firstname":"","lastname":"","nickname":"xxxxwedds","description":"","capabilities":"","avatar":null}}`

then you have to read [this nice tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) to use the resulting JSON in android (that's if you are new to android login) else just use your discretion.

Its really really really simple and interesting once you follow my lined up process.

Comment: the link of [teachattitude](http://techattitude.com/tips-tricks-and-hacks/how-to-remotely-create-a-user-on-your-wordpress-website-using-json-api-request/) seems to be broken

Comment: @ganjaam majorly the content of the link has been extracted in my answer above, the link is an indepth explanation to remote user creation using wordpress api.

Answer (score 1):

Use with clean Class

```
// Register REST API endpoints
class Login_REST_API_Endpoints {

    /**
     * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
     */
    public static function register_endpoints() {
        // endpoints will be registered here
        register_rest_route( 'wp', '/login', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array( 'Login_REST_API_Endpoints', 'login' ),
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|WP_REST_Request
     */
    public static function login( $request ) {


        $data = array();
        $data['user_login'] = $request["username"];
        $data['user_password'] =  $request["password"];
        $data['remember'] = true;
        $user = wp_signon( $data, false );

        if ( !is_wp_error($user) )
          return $user;
    }

}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( 'Login_REST_API_Endpoints', 'register_endpoints' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [WP REST User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/) it has create user and reset password functionality

And for login if you need advanced control over user capabilities use [AAM](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)

Comment: This plugin has been closed as of July 13, 2021 and is not available for download. Reason: Guideline Violation.

Answer (score 0):

###### 1.Paste Following code in your themes function.php file.

###### 2.Make sure that WP-REST-API plugin Should be installed on wordpress site

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks');
function register_api_hooks()
{
  register_rest_route(
    'wp/v2',
    '/login/',
    array(
      'methods' => 'POST',
      'callback' => 'gycs_login',
    )
  );
}
function gycs_login($request)
{
  $creds = array();
  $creds['user_login'] = sanitize_text_field($request["username"]);
  $creds['user_password'] = sanitize_text_field($request["password"]);
  $creds['remember'] = true;
  $user = wp_signon($creds, false);
  if (is_wp_error($user)) {
    return new WP_Error('authentication_failed', $user->get_error_message(), array('status' => 403));
  }
  return $user;
}
```

Then your API will be created as

`http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/login`