# android: combining android app with wordpress (login function)

Tags: php, android, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am currently working on a web & Android app project. I have a wordpress website, which has a login function for users. And now I have to write an Android app for the website.  However, the user passwords in the database are all encrypted. Can anybody can tell me how to access the passwords (check password) through the app in order to make the login function?

Comment: you can use same HTTP requests as the website does, and parse HTML that you get in response

Comment: reffer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679001/register-login-user-with-wordpress-json-api#answer-45531901