# Are WordPress REST API and WP JSON API different?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, api

I'm trying to code the user authentication feature for my app using API. I'm confused between [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and [WordPress JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)? Based on the [Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679001/register-login-user-with-wordpress-json-api), it says I need WordPress JSON API. If my WP already has REST API, do I still need this JSON API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they appear to be different.  The Wordpress REST API appears to be built into, and come with a Wordpress Installation.  I tested on [my site](https://instantcodepro.com), and was able to access the api for posts via a browser GET to [/wp-json/wp/v2/posts](https://instantcodepro.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts).  This is just an example.  I would imagine the other option you mentioned is a plugin that does something similar but the format of the requests look entirely different.  I would stick with the first solution that comes out of the box.

Comment: "First solution" meaning the REST API? But could that achieve the user authentication action?

Comment: Yes the REST API appears to be good for accessing posts, etc, however the user authentication piece only supports cookie authentication out of the box.  It looks like a plugin is required after all, as stated here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins