# Access Wordpress user info outside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress site and and now I'm building PHP App on subdomain. I need to get ID of the user who is logged in on Wordpress site.

I tried to include wp-load.php on my sub-domain and tried:

```
get_currentuserinfo();
echo 'Hey ' . $current_user->display_name;
```

But no result.

Could you please give me a hint how can I access Wordpress session info from outside Wordpress on Sub-domain and on the same server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only safe way would be to use an API. Try the wordpress api.

Answer (score 0):

Using the wordpress API would be the best way and as each case is a case it's not possible to get code ready for exactly what you say, but follow the documentation link about the api part that can help you:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

here you have another example of how to create endpoints for custom logins:
[Register/login user with Wordpress JSON API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679001/register-login-user-with-wordpress-json-api)

And this other one here of how to create a php request curl on another site that in your case would be the wordpress API:
https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/five-php-curl-examples