# How to access wordpress login rest api?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create API for my `wordpress` website in order to link the site with the android app I developed. I created a `json api` for `wp_users` table in `phpmyadmin` and it works perfect. But, there is a problem I can't figure out. The password of the users are shown up in hashed form. Here is how my API looks like:

```
"1": {
        "ID": 1,
        "user_login": "user1",
        "user_pass": "$P$BT6.fyjiaKZVEx/jM8sy5kC4QRkizg.",
        "user_nicename": "user1",
        "user_email": "user1@gmail.com",
        "user_url": "http://localhost/MyWebsite",
        "user_registered": "2021-10-27 21:29:02",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": 0,
        "display_name": "User1"
    },
    "2": {
        "ID": 2,
        "user_login": "user2",
        "user_pass": "$P$BArUGOBZAJfD1J3sE8OgRA3Bk1Ynfg/",
        "user_nicename": "user2",
        "user_email": "user2@gmail.com",
        "user_url": "",
        "user_registered": "2021-10-31 18:31:32",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": 0,
        "display_name": "User2"
    },
    "3": {
        "ID": 3,
        "user_login": "user3",
        "user_pass": "$P$B8rgiyaWrgWbkbFLMLlp2r7nIwFDwr.",
        "user_nicename": "user3",
        "user_email": "user3@gmail.com",
        "user_url": "",
        "user_registered": "2021-10-31 18:31:34",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": 0,
        "display_name": "User3"
    }
}
```

I found this on GitHub but in my website I can't search  `wp-json/user/login` or `wp-json/user/register`. So, is there another way to create API for `wordpress` or should I add something more in order to synchronize user authentication in both my website and the android app?

Comment: Did you write a completely custom API, or did you register a route with WordPress’s official built in JSON API?

Comment: Also, the passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I wrote a custom API. Oh, I see, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679001/register-login-user-with-wordpress-json-api

Comment: @JackLarson I tried it but I get this error: `"code": "jwt_auth_bad_auth_header",
    "message": "Authorization header malformed.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }`

Comment: @GusRasmusen, I would strongly recommend merging your code into the official API, unless you only want WordPress for authentication. WordPress also offers [“application passwords”](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) which are 24 character tokens that users can use for authentication. Otherwise, if the need to manually do something, look into using `wp_authenticate`, or the internals of `wp_check_password` if you really must roll your own (knowing WP could change this in the future).

Comment: @ChrisHaas What I want is to synchronize the website login and register with the android app login and register. So, what do you mean to merge the code into the official API?

Comment: What I mean is to move your API code into [WordPress’s official API handler](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) which will take care of routing, authentication, authorization and encoding for you. WordPress is “awake” inside so you also get access to all core functions and any plugins without hacking a manual boot up.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hmm, I see, alright thanks for your hep!